# Excel function for removing duplicates with a lower rank

Tags: excel, duplicates, highest

I receive a fuel consumption report each month. The report contains up to 600 vehicles, during the reporting period the same vehicle could fill up only once or multiple times resulting in duplicate entries with assending odometer readings.

I need to generate a list with two columns as below but I want remove duplicate vehicles (Rego No) and display the highest ODO/KM reading.

```
REGO NO   ODO/KMS          result
ccd500    58000            ccd500   60000
hhg900    34000            hhg900   36000
ccd500    58500            ccd800   58000
hhg900    34500            ccd900   35000
ccd800    58000
ccd900    35000
ccd500    60000
hhg900    36000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A2** thru **B9** use array formulas like:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$9="ccd500",$B$2:$B$9,))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.